# In ASP.NET, is there a way to write a custom Load Balancer?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, load-balancing

I have been working on implementing a (1) server, (n) worker role servers setup via WCF. One server handles requests, passes the work on via WCF to an available Worker Role, which processes the request, and passes the data back to the server. It's a bit too complicated for what I am able to handle. I'm trying to simplify the solution, and thought I could remove the WCF component by creating (n) servers, each capable of handling both the worker role service and the web server role. Assume each worker server is capable of only (1) worker role.

So that way, when a request comes in, some round-robin style handler picks an available server and forwards the HTTP request to that server/worker. That server/worker does the work, and returns the data directly to the requester.

Is this a feasible approach? I realize for some advanced developers, the WCF solution would pose no problem. I'm asking if there is a simpler, more hacked style approach that would allow me, with my limited ability, create a 1 server solution, then replicate and load balance multiple versions of that solution?

Any suggestions mucho apprecianado!

Comment: Ha! Thank you. Sorry for my terrible Spanish.

Comment: @ICarus: Your comment adds nothing to this and is offensive and rude. Get a life.

Comment: @kprobst I didn't mean to be rude. I was trying to promote spanish.stackexchange.com in which I participate. If I offended anybody here, specially Hairgami_Master, please accept my apologies.

Comment: @Icarus: Understood. Your comment just came across as hostile. My apologies to you as well.

Comment: No worries @Icarus. I love Spanish- wish I spoke it muy mejor!

Comment: @ChrisLively not really, the comment did come across as hostile. Thankfully Icarus clarified that was not his intent. So we're good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is precisely what Load Balancers are built for - they attempt to distribute incoming requests across a pool of available servers.

Many hosting companies offer hosting plans involving multiple servers which you can choose to load-balance incoming requests against.

For example: Rackspace offer load balancing as an optional feature of some of their hosting plans.

If you host a site with more than one web-role instances in Microsoft's Azure cloud, your site is automatically load balanced for you. You can also build your site such that it is dynamically load-balanced in multiple geographical regions also so that requests originating from, for example Asia, are routed to a datacenter in asia, reducing latency and intra-datacenter bandwidth.

Also, consider introducing queueing/message-bus between your front-end website and your back-end batch/intensive workload processing. This way you can independently scale the front and back ends of your system.

Having said all of the above, don't over-engineer your solution - focus on building a stable, solid, reliable, efficient system, then monitor and measure its performance and tune it where appropriate. Otherwise, you could spend valuable time and effort implementing features/tweaks that don't actually benefit the site or the user!

---

Update  2012-01-31 based on OP's comments:

If you want to make your worker roles perform one task at a time and only go back for another piece of work when they're no longer busy, I suggest you invert your architecture:

[image]

Instead of having some front-end server try to work out which of the workers is "busy" and distribute work accordingly, consider having your front-end server queue incoming messages into an "incoming" queue.

Workers "pull" a new work-item from the front-end, perform whatever work is required and then inform the front-end that the work is complete and ask for another work-item.

The beauty with this approach is that it can scale in a linear fashion and can be HIGHLY resilient.

When a worker "pulls" a new work item, the front-end timestamps the message and moves it to a secondary "pending" queue. Workers inform the front-end when they're done with a work-item; the front-end moves completed items to a "completed" queue (or deletes them if it doesn't care).

The front-end can then run a periodic scan of the "pending" queue, looking for messages that have been waiting too long and can return those messages to the "incoming" queue if they've been pending for too long.

Queues can be A LOT of fun :) However, building such a queueing system can be complex and making it truly reliable can be time consuming and costly.

Luckily, you can take advantage of some very proficient message-bus implementations that'll provide you with 90% of what you'll need to make this happen! My favorite is Microsoft's cloud-based [Azure Message Bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732537.aspx) which provides you a pretty bullet-proof durable-messaging, pub-sub and queueing infrastructure that's ideally suited to your scenario.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Richard- I have a very, very special edge case I'm dealing with, and need to pretend as if each server is a Singleton, able to deal with only one request at a time. I'm trying to come up with a load balancing solution for this unique case- if you can think of anything that might help, I'm all ears. Cheers!

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative approach that may suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend this. Balancing seems simple to most developers at first ("hey I'll just keep track of each request and forward the next one to the next server in line, etc") but in reality it is complicated if it's not completely trivial. You need to think about maintaining load quotas per server, handling servers that go down, etc.

If you're already running Server 2008 it's probably cheaper and easier (and far more performant) to use the NLB features of the OS instead of coming up with your own. [This](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Building_a_Windows_Server_2008_Network_Load_Balancing_Cluster) for example is a good walkthrough of setting up an NLB cluster.

Ultimately of course the approach is up to you, but I think using the right tools for the job is always a good idea. Re-inventing round robin IP clustering in a WCF service seems like a waste of time if you have that baked into the OS already.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @kprobst! In this particular edge case, I need to pretend as if each server is a Singleton, able to serve only 1 client at a time. If any particular server is busy, the load balancer will need to look for another server that is not busy. There is no ASP session or state to worry about. Does that make you think any differently?

Comment: @Hairgami_Master But how would you decide if a particular server is busy? That kind of complexity can get really old really quickly as you try to scale this to a real-world scenario. Like I said, if your balancing needs are relatively simple then I suppose your approach would work, but it's not something I would choose as a long-term solution.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a simple way to make an IHttpHandler a singleton... Something that would make a simple request to that handler fail if it was busy; something that I could easily detect and move on and try the next server if it was busy. Perhaps there isn't a way to do this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a completely different approach.

Namely, instead of pushing a job to a particular server, let each server in the farm poll for jobs as they are available.

The primary reason for this is your requirement that each server is "able to serve only 1 client at a time".

---

So, to set things up:

1. A request comes in.
2. The request is logged to a Work table
3. One of your work servers makes a request for the next job.
4. It is assigned to that server.
5. Once the work is complete, the server marks it as done.

Now, this gives you some options.  First off it's trivial to reassign... Just clear out what server the job is currently assigned to.  You might have a monitor watching this table and, if a job is taking "too long" then you can simply allow a different server to grab it.

Further, you can add or remove worker servers at will, without having to notify some type of controlling server that a machine is now online or offline.

---

For a little more robustness you could have each worker server check in with your database to indicate that it is ready for work.  The servers would then check in once every few seconds to see if anything has been assigned.

A SQL job could be executing every so often that assigns the work.  It could also be responsible for reassigning in the event a machine has taken too long to process it.

Comment: Hi Chris- Thanks for your suggestion. I'm currently doing something like this via Amazon SQS. Although it works OK, it's not fast enough, and I'm trying to come up with a solution that removes all the writing to SQS, polling for message, take job, do work, write result of work somewhere, etc.. I can make one server do this so easily, it seems like if I just duplicated that one server, and came up with an intelligent way of load balancing across multiple servers, it would be a simple solution. :)

Comment: @Hairgami_Master: Your primary problem is how to deal with the inevitable machine failure.  As you scale, machines are going to pop in and out of availability.  Depending on implementation, polling a list of machines for availability might actually take *longer* than just letting them request it.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. Thanks.